# how to compare intercepts from the same regression line

Tags: r

Hi I did a Mixed effect model as demonstrated below and I want to compare the intercepts from the summary output.

```
library (lme4)
seed3<-lmer(logvar~logmean+Gene*Stage+logmean*Stage+(1|Year)+(1|Location), data=data_pod_seed, REML=TRUE)
summary(seed3)
library(car)
Anova(seed3)


As results I got this:


    Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                0.70401    0.22749    3.23
logmean                    1.65606    0.01845   84.32
GeneRag1                   0.07302    0.04273    1.71
GeneRag1+Rag2             -0.13085    0.05524   -2.37
StageFLOWER               -0.32120    0.05885   -5.46
StagePOD                  -0.68914    0.07782   -8.86
StageSEED                 -0.83973    0.09092   -9.24
GeneRag1:StageFLOWER       0.12829    0.07173    1.79
GeneRag1+Rag2:StageFLOWER  0.14218    0.08513    1.67
GeneRag1:StagePOD          0.12122    0.06687    1.81
GeneRag1+Rag2:StagePOD     0.24638    0.10207    2.41
GeneRag1:StageSEED         0.11211    0.08852    1.27
GeneRag1+Rag2:StageSEED    0.39355    0.10815    3.64
logmean:StageFLOWER        0.09845    0.03508    2.81
logmean:StagePOD           0.20310    0.03381    6.01
logmean:StageSEED          0.33243    0.04055    8.20
```

I want to do a Wald test to compare the parameters from the fixed effect to see if they are different from each other.(for example: intercept with StagePOD).  How Can I do that using R?

Comment: I'm not sure about what do you mean by "comparing the intercepts and the slopes". But it case it is of any help, you can get the intercept and the slope as a numeric vector as model.fit$coefficients, where the first position will correspond to the Intercept, and the sucesive to the slopes. So that way yo can name variables using these values and the "compare" them in the way you want to

Comment: I want to compare for example: logmean with logmean:StagePOD. I have an interaction so I want to know what is different from what.

Comment: Not clear what you want to do ? You want to plot the slope ?

Comment: No I want to see which slope is different from each other.